# Can I change the direction the Start Screen scrolls in?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Instead of scrolling left to right, can I scroll top to bottom? I seem to remember someone saying you could change this, but I have yet to find an option. Is it instead possible with Windows RT?

Comment: I don't think there is an official way to do this. I'm not sure of any 3rd party Apps though.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a registry setting or a hack somewhere. Who knows?

Comment: would be nice to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app called [Start Screen Animations Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.146) that allows you to do exactly that:

[image]

All I had to do was drag the "Left-to-right animation offset" slider all the way to the right to achieve the effect you've described.